# Delete timestamp in my output file in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I need to remove timestamps in my file. It should only return the name. My source text file looks like this

```
7:52:01 AM sherr
hello GOOD morning .
おはようございます。
7:52:09 AM sherr
Who ?
誰?
7:52:16 AM sherr
OK .
わかりました
```

and my code looks like this

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import copy

wb = Workbook()

with open('chat_20220207131707.txt', encoding='utf-8') as sherr:
    row = 1
    column = 1
    ws = wb.active
    for line in sherr:
        ws.cell(row=row, column=column, value=line.strip())
        if (column := column + 1) > 3:
            row += 1
            column = 1

    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:      
            alignment = copy.copy(cell.alignment)
            alignment.wrapText=True
            cell.alignment = alignment
            
    wb.save('sherrplease.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hey, kyjsml. What symptom did you get? If I understand correctly, you're trying to read a plain text file using an Excel library, but the file is not structured like an Excel doc at all. It looks like ordinary lines of text, ready for straightforward Python text processing.

Comment: Yes because my input is from txt file and my output should be in excel file, and I need to remove the timestamps from that txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* the file always has the same structure, which it certainly looks like, this can be done with simple splitting of the string in question.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import copy

wb = Workbook()

with open('chat_20220207131707.txt', encoding='utf-8') as sherr:
    row = 1
    column = 1
    ws = wb.active
    for line in sherr:
        if column == 1:
            ## split the line and rejoin
            value = " ".join(line.strip().split(' ')[2:])
        else:
            value = line.strip()
        ws.cell(row=row, column=column, value=value)
        if (column := column + 1) > 3:
            row += 1
            column = 1

    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:      
            alignment = copy.copy(cell.alignment)
            alignment.wrapText=True
            cell.alignment = alignment
            
    wb.save('sherrplease.xlsx')
```